# How to debug mutex deadlock in android jni

Tags: android, android-ndk, deadlock

I'm maintaining a c++ library which will be used in Android application.
I found it sometimes will hang like a deadlock.
The code architecture is very complicated, I can just describe roughly here. The library has two thread T1 and T2, both runs in its while loop. (Continuously updates the data type)

```
T1::Run() {
  while (1) {
    // Compute so many data type Obj1 and Obj2
    // So many for loop which will step by step to handle each Obj1   
    // and Obj2.
    std::cout << "T1++" << std::endl;
    for () { ... }
    for () { ... }
    std::cout << "T1--" << std::endl;
  }
}

T2::Run() {
  while (1) {
    // Compute so many data type Obj1 and Obj2
    // So many for loop which will step by step to handle each Obj1   
    // and Obj2.
    std::cout << "T2++" << std::endl;
    for () { ... }
    for () { ... }
    std::cout << "T2--" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Data type Obj1 and Obj2 both have several mutex. And they will lock their mutex in multiple member functions.

```
class Obj1 {
  std::mutex mutex1;
  std::mutex mutex2;
  std::mutex mutex3;
  void fun1() { unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex1); }
  void fun2() { unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex2);
                // Do something...
                // Another Obj1 instance : temp
                temp->fun3().
                // ... }
  void fun3() { unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex1);
                unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex3);
                // Do something...
                // Another Obj2 instance : temp
                temp->fun1().
                // ... }
}

class Obj2 {
  std::mutex mutex1;
  std::mutex mutex2;
  std::mutex mutex3;
  void fun1() { unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex1); }
  void fun2() { unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex2); }
  void fun3() { unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex1);
                unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex3); }
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a useful way to verify if it is really a deadlock problem.
I tried to print log, but I can only make sure that when the library hangs, the log "T1++" or "T2++" was printed but "T1--" and "T2--" didn't.
If I tried to print more log in each for loop, then the log will be too much, and the deadlock will hard to be reproduced. (Timing problem)

I think the usage of Obj1::fun2() and Obj1::fun3 has potential deadlock problem. Because Obj1 will lock its mutex first and then call another Obj1 instance's member function (this member function also locks this instance mutex), as T1 and T2 will call Obj1::fun2() and fun3() simultaneously, the deadlock may be triggered. I've added a new global mutex for these kind member function, but it's not useful.

I want to ask if there is any tool that can identify which thread is blocked by which mutex? Or any other advice for these scenario?